# What are the products for the redox reaction HCl + SnCl₂ + KMnO₄?

Tags: redox, titration

In the redox reaction, where **$\ce{HCl}$ is the excess reactant** do these reactions produce following half reactions?
\begin{aligned}
(1)&&\ce{SnCl2 &-> Sn^{4+} + 2e-}\\
(2)&&\ce{8H+ + KMnO4 + 5e- &-> Mn^{2+} + 4H2O}
\end{aligned}

Where does the $\ce{HCl}$ come into play here, or do you consider it at the end when you have a final equation?

This is a redox reaction where $\ce{KMnO4}$ was added to $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{SnCl2}$ (hydrochloric acid was simply used as an excess reagent)

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. I edited your post to make the chemical equations pretty using MathJax. More information here:http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: @BenNorris Dear Ben, I believe it is $H_2O$ not $H_{20}$. :)

Comment: @Jun-GooKwak - fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ce{KMnO4 + SnCl2 + HCl -> KCl + MnCl2 + SnCl4 + H2O}$$

Oxidation states are for reactants:
\begin{aligned}\ce{
K  &= +1\\
Mn &= +7\\
O  &= -2 \\
Sn &= +2\\
Cl &= -1\\
H  &= +1\\
}\end{aligned}

Oxidation states for products:
\begin{aligned}\ce{
K  &= +1\\
Cl &= -1\\
Mn &= +2\\
Sn &= +4\\
H  &= +1\\
O  &= -2\\
}\end{aligned}

This is a redox reaction carried out in acidic solution. $\ce{SnCl2}$ and $\ce{KMnO4}$ are titrated with hydrochloric acid. What is being oxidized and what is being reduced? Potassium is being reduced, magnesium and tin are oxidized.

Let's write out our half reactions:

\begin{aligned}\ce{
HCl + SnCl2 &-> SnCl\\
HCl + KMnO4 &-> MnCl2 + KCl + H2O
}\end{aligned}

If we look at the oxidation states of our reactants, and products, $\ce{H}$ has +1, $\ce{Cl}$ -1, and for the products $\ce{Sn}$ +2, $\ce{Cl}$ -1 for the first reaction. The first reaction gains two electrons and thus is reduced.

For the 2nd reaction, $\ce{H}$ again has +1 and $\ce{Cl}$ -1. Potassium has +1 and the permanganate ion has -2. Specifically, $\ce{Mn}$ has a theoretical oxidation state of +7 and oxygen -2. In the products side, magnesium has an oxidation state of +2 and $\ce{Cl}$ -1, $\ce{H}$ is +1, $\ce{O}$ is 2-, and $\ce{K}$ becomes +1. Chlorine as an element has an oxidation state of 0.

For redox reactions, we have to make sure our reactants and products are first balanced for our elements other than H and O in acidic solution. It is clear that the chlorines are not balanced, therefore:

\begin{aligned}\ce{
2HCl + SnCl2 &-> SnCl4 \\
3HCl + KMnO4 &-> MnCl2 + KCl + H2O
}\end{aligned}

We balance oxygen atoms with adding molecules of water:

\begin{aligned}\ce{
2HCl + SnCl2 &-> SnCl4\\
3HCl + KMnO4 &-> MnCl2 + KCl + 4H2O 
}\end{aligned}

Now we add H+ to balance H:

\begin{aligned}\ce{
2HCl + SnCl2 &-> SnCl4 + 2H+\\
3HCl + KMnO4 + 5H+ &-> MnCl2 + KCl + 4H2O 
}\end{aligned}

We now add electrons to balance charge:

\begin{aligned}\ce{
2HCl + SnCl2 + 2e- &-> SnCl4 + 2H+\\
3HCl + KMnO4 + 5H+ &-> MnCl2 + KCl + 4H2O + 5e- 
}\end{aligned}

We multiply our half-reactions by integers so that the electrons are the same number:

\begin{aligned}\ce{
10HCl + 5SnCl2 + 10e- &-> 5SnCl4 + 10H+\\
6 HCl + 2KMnO4 + 10H+ &-> 2MnCl2 + 2KCl + 8H2O + 10e-
}\end{aligned}

Now we add 'em up and cancel:

\begin{aligned}\ce{
16HCl + 5SnCl2 + 2KMnO4 &-> 5SnCl4 + 2MnCl2 + 2KCl + 8H2O
}\end{aligned}

Comment: I think Sn loses 2 electrons, while Mn gains 5 electrons

Comment: Ah... this question is long. I almost got it. I think I wrote one of the half-reactions wrong, let me look it up.

Comment: The final equation should be 16H+ + 2KMnO4 + 5SnCl2 ==> 5SnCl4 + 2MnCl2 + 8H2O + 2KCl

Comment: @Jonie Sn loses 2. Mn gains 4.

Comment: no Mn gains 5, it goes from +7 to +2

Comment: oxidation number of K is +1

Comment: Are you sure that the equation you provided is correct? I added up everything and it checks out. Ah ok, thank you. I thought potassium was an alkaline earth. Thanks, I'll rework that.

Comment: No problem, and thank you for taking the time out to help me, i really appreciate it! I just dont understand why Cl2 forms in your products

Comment: Got it. Few more edits. I used the wrong half reactions.

Comment: what happened to the 10H+?

Comment: btw since Sn is being oxidized, the electrons should be in the products, and since the Mn is being reduced, the electrons should be in the reactants, but this is just a technical error

Comment: In hindsight that's correct, the reduction phase of a cathode half-reaction has the electrons in the reactants side. I think I can leave that for you to figure out and I believe this question is resolved. Thanks.

Comment: but what happens to the 10 H+

Comment: It's canceled out on both sides just like the electrons.

Comment: My pleasure. :)

Answer (score 6):

When using $\ce{MnO4-}$ as an oxidant, pH is **crucial**.

In acidic medium: $\ce{Mn(VII) -> Mn(II)}$

$$\ce{8 H3O+ + MnO4^{-} + 5 e- -> Mn^{2+} + 12 H2O}$$

Under neutral conditions: $\ce{Mn(VII) -> Mn(IV)}$

$$\ce{2 H2O + MnO4^{−} + 3 e− -> MnO2 + 4 OH^{−}}$$

In strongly alkaline medium: $\ce{Mn(VII) -> Mn(VI)}$

$$\ce{MnO4^{−} + e− -> MnO4^{2−}}$$

As far as an excess of $\ce{HCl}$ is concerned, one might take into account that $\ce{Sn(II)}$ and $\ce{Sn(IV)}$ possibly exist as their anionic chloro complexes 
$\ce{[Sn(Cl)4]^{2-}}$ and $\ce{[Sn(Cl)6]^{2-}}$, respectively.