# In a redox reaction, why does more than one oxidation state of an element form?

Tags: acid-base, redox, aqueous-solution, ions, oxidation-state

Consider the reaction **100ml 10M** $\ce{NaOH_{(aq)}} +$ **100ml 10M** $\ce{NaHSO3_{(aq)} +}$ **100mL 0.01M** $\ce{KMnO4_{(aq)}}$

In the picture posted here, the left columns give information on the Molarity of species present **before** 100mL 0.01 M $\ce{KMnO4}$ is added. The right column is **after** $\ce{KMnO4}$ is added.

[image: Redox Reaction]

In the resulting solution, $\ce{Mn}$ is oxidized to various states: $\ce{Mn^2+ Mn^4+ Mn^6+ Mn^7+}$ (where $\ce{Mn^7+}$ is the original form).

I would like to know, why do different oxidation states of $\ce{Mn}$ appear? How can we predict the concentration of oxidation states?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/8714/4945) answer is of any help.

Comment: Actually, $Mn^{7+}$ is reduced to $Mn^{6+}$, $Mn^{4+}$ and $Mn^{2+}$ and $SO_3^{2+}$ is oxidized to $SO_4^{2+}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They all appear because they are all finite amount of energy apart, but note that some concentrations are many orders of magnitude greater than others, and the concentration of $\ce{MnO4-}$ is so low that the table shows a zero.

Predicting the concentration requires being able to read tables of potentials. In standard tables like http://bilbo.chm.uri.edu/CHM112/tables/redpottable.htm  you will find equations such as $$\ce{MnO2{}+4H+ +4e-  \rightleftharpoons Mn + 2H2O}\quad (1.23\mathrm{V})$$ and $$\ce{Mn^{2+}{}+2e^-  \rightleftharpoons Mn}\quad (-1.185\mathrm{V})$$ (the numbers in parentheses are the standard reduction potentials, $E^\circ$, always measured in volts).

With this and the Nernst equation you can relate the concentrations of any set of species that form a balanced reaction.  In a complicated mix like this you don't know a priori the concentration of any species, only the certain sums (for instance, for all sulfur-containing ions) but you still can, perhaps iteratively, solve the corresponding set of algebraic equations and find the individual concentrations.  *All* the equilibrium equations have to be satisfied simultaneously; if they aren't the system is not in equilibrium.

(In this answer I've used the word "concentration" but the equations written with concentrations are only approximately satisfied; to account for second-order effects the notion of "activity" was introduced, and while it is an essentially empirical notion, it's still useful if the dependence of activity on concentration for a particular problem has been tabulated.)